# Where i can download MotoDev Studio?

Tags: android, motorola-droid, motodev-studio

In the new Motorola Website i can't find any link to MotoDev Studio.
I used it in the last year and now it seems disappeared.

Do you know where can i find last builds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not supporting MotoDev studio anymore.  This has to do with the restructure after the purchase from Google.

I am not sure about downloading legacy builds, but Motorola isn't actively developing this anymore (and laid off most of the team that was working on this).

You might search for "MOTODEV Core Plugins", as they renamed studio to that - but you probably want to not use these tools anymore, since they are not being supported moving forward.

Comment: They did open source everything, so at least all the good stuff they did isn't locked inside a corporation somewhere.  Hopefully some of the innovative stuff will make its way into to the official ADT.