# Motodev site hanging Eclipse check for updates

Tags: android, eclipse, motorola, motodev-studio

I'm a bit new to Eclipse and Android development. A few months back I had installed the motodev environment, which since has been shutdown ([Where i can download MotoDev Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219353/where-i-can-download-motodev-studio)).

I have removed the motodev environment per Motorola's instructions but the problem I'm having though is that I still have motodev websites in my "Available Software Sites" in Eclipse. Upon running a check updates in Eclipse, it just hangs on this website - https://studio-android.motodevupdate.com/android/1.2/adt/

Here is the snippet from the Eclipse error log:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf 2 0 2012-11-22 12:40:28.607
!MESSAGE Connection to https://studio-android.motodevupdate.com/android/1.2/adt/p2.index failed on Connection refused. Retry attempt 0 started
!STACK 0
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
```

I'm on Mac OS Mountain Lion and I have tried going to Preferences -> Install/Update -> Available Software Sites. I have removed it and also disabled it but each time after restarting Eclipse it is added back into the list or re-enabled and again freezes the check update process (help -> check for updates).

I can work around the issue by going in and disabling/deleting the entry, then immediately running check for updates. The problem only occurs after restarting Eclipse and the site is added back/re-enabled.

How can I get rid of this silly problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Eclipse, go to Window | Preferences | Install/Updates | Available Software Sites; from there, uncheck (disable) the following components:

```
Motodev Plugins
MotodevPlugins
Sequoyah Metadata Repository
https://studio-android.motodevupdate.com/android/4.0/
https://studio-android.motodevupdate.com/android/4.0/basic/
https://studio-android.motodevupdate.com/android/4.1/
```

Sequoyah is an old independant component that is usually installed before Motodev because it's needed for Motodev.  It is no longer maintened and probably that you should remove it as well after removing Motodev.

The last three in the list are not designed here by the name of their componenent but by their location as they are unnamed sites. (At least, they are unnamed on my personal installation).  You should also check carefully for any other sites related to either Motodev or Sequoyah.

After that, not only you shouldn't have any more error but the update checking should perform much more faster.

BTW, when you are there, take the time for checking for other older, unused components/versions.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to navigate to:

> [eclipse install] -> configuration -> org.eclipse.update -> platform.xml

In that file, you'll want to remove the `<feature>` tag containing the MotoDev plugin.

Additionally, you'll also want to navigate to:

> [eclipse install] -> features

Here you can find the MotoDev plugin folder and remove it.

I'm not entirely sure what the MotoDev plugin's package name is since I've never used it but it'll most likely start off with `com.motorola`.

Answer (score 0):

That's true. I tasted 
[eclipse install] -> configuration -> org.eclipse.update -> platform.xml
I erase all my configuration and I don't know where was it.

I have to reinstall serveral times eclipse but dosn't work. And a navigate .eclispe/platform/configuration/org.eclipse.update/platform.xml
delete this and restart.
And work it.